# Django request is loop when request take long time

Tags: django

I have an issue when making a submit form POST request. Sometimes My request is being looped when it takes a long time to respond. Somehow a new request similar to the previous request is made, and I don't know where is it from? I have tried to debug, create traceback, but have no idea where is it called. It usually happens when the request is made from the Chrome Browser on macOS. Do you guys have any idea why does it happen?

Django version 1.11.17

I use uWSGI for hosting services. I use HTop to debug. I have noticed that whenever the request is looped, the process is running again. Is it cause the bug

[image]

I have made a simple test. calling function with sleep

```
@login_required()
def main(request):
    for i in xrange(1200, 0, -1):
        if i == 1200:
            logger.info('--Start--')
        logger.info('Sleep {}'.format(str(i)))
        sleep(1)
```

Here is the log when the request is a call again.

First time

[image]

Loop Happen

[image]

Comment: You'll need to give more details if you want help. What do you see in your django console? Is this on your development machine or in production? What do you mean by "request is being looped"? What requests do you see in your chrome dev tools?

Comment: @dirkgroten 
it's actually is submit the form
it's happening both the development machine and production.

`request is being looped`: It's mean the function handle this request is called again. 

I have made a log at the function which handles the request. The task was called again with a similar previous request. 

I have use uWSGI for my Django application

Comment: @dirkgroten I have added more detail.